# Define a dataObject and pass it to the next view in Flashbuilder

Tags: view, flash-builder

I am trying to convert my java-app for Android to a Flex/Air app with Flashbuilder.
I am nearly there (thanks to sample code on Adobe) but have problems with passing data between  views.
I have 3 views. The first have a list of items and an event handler that choose one of this list items and pass this to the next view:

```
<s:List id="list" left="0" top="0" bottom="0" width="768"
change="navigator.pushView(Intro, list.selectedItem)" dataProvide "{data}">
```

This works fine and I can use the values stored in {data}.
e.g.

```
<s:Label text="{data.title}"/>
```

Now I want to pass the same data on a button click to the next view, spelaView.
Something like this:

```
 <s:Button id="backBtn" label="Spela"
 click="navigator.pushView(SpelaSaga, dataObj)" />
```

Sorry to say, I do not know how I transform the data-object {data} (with three items: data.title, data.description, data.audio) to **dataObj** in a form that the next view are abel to use.
Hope someone is kind enough to give me some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.
Defined this function and could then get the data in the next view

```
        protected function spelaSaga():void{ 
            var dataObj:Object=
                {
            titel:data.title bild:data.description, audio:data.audio

                };  
            navigator.pushView(views.SpelaSaga, dataObj);
        }
```